# Azure AAD MSAL calls resulting in AADSTS50196 exception The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, azure-ad-msal

We are using MSAL to get the Auth Token and giving a call to Dynamics CRM (using the username and password) and then hoping the cached token is leveraged on subsequent request. All works fine when we have 1 user accesing it but in our load test where we have 50 concurrent users hitting in a 1 minute time this raises exception:

```
(AADSTS50196: The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop. Please contact your app vendor.
```

I understand and read about the throtlling of the requests here:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Throttling

But I am still not sure how and what has gone wrong with the code below that its not using the cached token and causing the app to fail, can someone help me here figure what is wrong with my code and what changes I can do to make it work? Appreciate your help

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;

namespace XXX.YYYYYYYY.Administration.Functions.PanelManagement
{
    public partial class CrmService: ICrmService
    {
        private IMemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions {ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)});
        private Guid cacheKey = Guid.NewGuid();

        public string RequestToken(string serviceUrl, string clientId, string redirectUrl, string username, string password)
        {
            // check if token exist in memory cache
            AuthenticationResult current = null;
            if (memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out AuthenticationResult value))
                current = value;

            if (current != null && current.ExpiresOn < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow && current.ExtendedExpiresOn < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                return current.AccessToken;

            //Build Microsoft.Identity.Client (MSAL) OAuth Token Request
            var authBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                            .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
                            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl)
                            .Build();
            var scope = serviceUrl + "//.default";
            string[] scopes = { scope };

            AuthenticationResult authBuilderResult;
            if (username != string.Empty && password != string.Empty)
            {
                //Make silent Microsoft.Identity.Client (MSAL) OAuth Token Request
                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
                authBuilderResult = authBuilder.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, securePassword)
                            .ExecuteAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                //Popup authentication dialog box to get token
                authBuilderResult = authBuilder.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                            .ExecuteAsync().Result;
            }

            current = authBuilderResult;

            // update cache, let the cache expires in 50 minutes so token can be renewed before it expires
            memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, current, current.ExpiresOn.AddMinutes(-10));  

            //Note that an Azure AD access token has finite lifetime, default expiration is 60 minutes.
            return current.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution and it was issue with the datetime comparison with ExpiresOn and Current time ) following is incorrect comparision:

```
if (current != null && current.ExpiresOn < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow && current.ExtendedExpiresOn < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                return current.AccessToken
```

Fixing this to below and re-running it causes it to pick the token from cache:

```
if (current != null && current.ExpiresOn > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow && current.ExtendedExpiresOn > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                return current.AccessToken
```